# Why do I suck at combat?

Tags: fable-3

I've been playing Fable III for a while now, up to a point where I purchased level 3 upgrades to my battle skills. For some reason, I seem to be totally miserable in combat.

I open each battle with ranged attacks on the closest enemies, blast them with a spell as they get closer and then try to finish them off with some swordplay. However, they quickly gang up on me from all directions and kill me dead. I try to use spells to stun them, but not all enemies inside the blast radius are affected. I try to parry, but that doesn't help against the guys who are rear-ending me.

I've barely started the game and have already kicked the bucket four times. Even my own weapons are mocking me by turning to bone because of my "fragility in combat". The previous game of the series I've played was the original Fable, which I completed twice and I don't remember coming even close to dying even once.

What could I be doing wrong? Or is dying at this pace normal?

Comment: How can someone be bad at this game? It was basically made to be a "Press A to win" game. Hell, even dying has no visible cons.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm worried. I'm not used to being bad at games, especially the ones generally considered unchallenging.

Comment: If you die enough, there is scarring.  I like to finish my game pretty ;)

Comment: i sucked at combat too for while but if u practice and see videos on youtube you will get better

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, I've played through Fable 3 four times now and I've gone down all three combat paths: Spells, Ranged, Melee and of the three Melee is by far the hardest.  I listed them in what I found to be easiest to hardest, but the jump from ranged to Melee is pretty big.

However, if you want to do melee, let's talk about melee.

### Rolling

The first thing you're going to need to figure out how to do is roll your way out of a group.  Rolling is the special sauce that makes combat in Fable easy.  Normally if you're running magic or ranged, you just roll->shoot and call it a day.  However, with melee you leave yourself open when you attack so you'll want to not just roll to avoid attacks, but actually roll out of groups.  The trick here is that you never want to have an enemy behind you when you start attacking.  This often means you'll need a half dozen successive rolls to give yourself a nice position where all enemies are in the same direction as you.

### Attacking

Because of the way the AI pathing works, your enemies will spread out a little as they come at you, but they generally won't envelope you.  What usually happens is that your attack combo brings you forward inside of the group.  This is kind of the worse possible position so usually you'll want to keep your attack combo's short (ie. 2-3 hits) and then roll back out.

### Rinse and Repeat

The problem with this strategy is that it'll take a while to take down any decent sized group.  Some things that you'll find help are picking a faster weapon (to get a feel for the pace) and trying to engage smaller groups.  This will leave less opportunity to get surrounded and beat down.  Finally, always remember to roll towards a section you've already cleared.  You don't want to roll into another group and make things harder for yourself.

---

### Ranged

Ranged works similarly to Melee is that you roll away from the group except now you can just start shooting, instead of waiting for them to get close.  Don't bother charging up shots, its rarely worth it.  Just keep firing away and rolling out of range.  Most mobs will wait before chasing you so you'll have ample time to light them up.

### Magic

I found Magic to be absurdly easy.  No mana  bar means you can spam spells, and the ability to charge them up usually means I entered every battle with my enemies half dead.  I liked something with electricity (for stun) and fire (for damage).  When I see a group of enemies run at me, I start charging.  Get a nice big AoE charge while I wait for them all to get in range and release.  This'll just about kill off the smaller mobs and wound the larger ones.  Then I roll away and do it again.  I rarely ever use direct attacks unless there is only one big mob left.

Comment: Thanks! This seems definitely helpful, I'm currently hardly rolling at all and comboing a lot. I'll try reversing that and see if my battles get less humiliating.

Comment: +1. Melee without rolling is quite frustrating; melee with plenty of rolling looks really dumb and is highly effective. There were a couple of mobs where I found direct magic to be helpful, but other than that I went with the AoE as described above.